# Vlan cannot get DHCP address from using Router and L3 Switch

Tags: vlan, dhcp, packet-tracer

Simplified diagram of a larger network, but I'm having trouble getting DHCP from the router. Going into simulation mode in packet tracer, I'm seeing an error on the layer 3 switch saying "There is no subinterface with this VLAN enabled"

[image]

Router Config

```
en
conf t
int gig 0/1
ip address 205.165.85.5 255.255.255.252
no shut
int gig 0/1.5
encapsulation dot1q 5
ip address 192.168.86.30 255.255.255.240
!
ip dhcp pool vlan5
network 192.168.86.16 255.255.255.240
default-router
end
```

Switch

```
en
conf t
ip routing
vtp domain ndd430
vtp mode server
vlan 5
int fa0/1
switchport access vlan 5
spanning-tree portfast
!
int gig 0/2
no switchport
ip address 205.165.85.6 255.255.255.252
no shut
int vlan 5
ip address 192.168.86.30 255.255.255.240
ip helper-address 205.165.85.5
end
```

EIGRP

```
router eigrp 100
network 205.165.85.4 0.0.0.3
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the configurations of the network devices.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Network Engineering!

The problem is your switch configuration.  You have Gi0/2 configured as a L3 interface, but the router is a trunk port.

Moreover, you have your 192.168.86.16/28 subnet split between two separate networks:  One on the router and one on the switch, but they are not connected at layer 2.

Change your switch config to this:

```
int gig 0/2
switchport
switchport mode trunk
```

Also, remove the helper address on int vlan5

Answer (score 0):

The optimised way is modify  this setup as fallow ..
Disadvantages if DHCP are configured in router

Router and switch are   connected with L3 interface in middle DHCP traffic to pass from L3 interface requires DHCP relay . To avoid this scenario..

1. Move DHCP configuration from router to layer3 switch . Beacuse end devices are directly connected to layer3 switch . And layer3 switch has capabilities of handling DHCP traffic without any issues .

Or els keeping DHCP configuration in router and allow router and switch connectivity link with trunk port in switch allowing all Vlans .